# Fill texture with white color

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, libgdx, opengl-es2

How to paint texture with white color? Example what I mean:
[image]

`SpriteBatch.setColor` changes tint only.

Comment: A simple shader should be enough.

Comment: If you want to do this permanently, just write a for-loop over all pixels and if Alpha>0 then set Red, Green and Blue to 255.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated above, simply implementing a pixel shader to change the color would be sufficient. Other than that, you could swap out textures on the fly. That is a bigger performance hit though, by far.